# Disable sounds on Opera 12.17 on Windows

Tags: windows, audio, opera

On older versions of Opera, there was an option to disable sounds on a webpage.

This was present on Opera 12.16 and I had used it.

Now, I have Opera 12.17 and lost all my settings due to a reinstall.

How can I disable the sound on this specific version?

---

I know this is a very ancient version of Opera, but I must use it.

Other browsers cause problems with my graphic card (locking it at 400mhz) or burn my memory (looking at you Google Chrome!) which makes this version of Opera the only one I can use.

This is because Facebook is SOOOOOOOOOOOO slow that is nearly useless.
It takes around 20s-3h to open a webpage!
And everytime I receive a message, Opera uses 25% of my CPU.
Disabling the sound helps to ease the CPU a little.

I use Facebook A LOT!
If there is any way to disable the sound, I will be VERY happy!

Comment: (My comment isn't an answer for what you ask. However, I had the same problem with Opera 12.17 and Facebook. More than 30s loading time. I modified my `..\Opera\profile\override.ini` and deleted all entries regarding [www.facebook.com]. After that it loads instantly. please try that and report back

Comment: @nixda **HOLY MOTHER OF GOD!!!** It works!!! Thank you so much!!! Facebook now takes 2 seconds to load **everytime**!!! I don't know if this makes any difference but I have installed Opera in a ramdisk (using ImDisk, http://reboot.pro/files/file/284-imdisk-toolkit/) as an USB installation and I changed the file `R:\Opera\profile\override_downloaded.ini` instead. Instead of simply deleting the lines, I have commented them (lines 691 and 692). And IT WORKS!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line under [www.facebook.com] in *override.ini*

```
Multimedia|PlayBackgroundSound = 0
```

Comment: Since my installation is in a ramdisk installed as a USB installation, the file is `R:\Opera\profile\override_downloaded.ini`. For now, I can't confirm because I didn't received a message on facebook yet. Reading the comment that @nixda left will help you with speed issues. I'm just waiting for a message and I will inform you if I had success or not.

Comment: It seems to work. Thank you a lot for the tip! I have upvoted your answer and marked it as accepted.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not aware there is such an option neither in Opera 12.16 or 12.17.
By entering preferences (Alt+P), under "Advanced" tab, in "Notifications" section, you can access all options related to sound in Opera.

Comment: This doesn't help because this is only the sounds of the notifications, like when a file is finished downloading or when Opera Turbo kicks in the warnings. If you look at http://help.opera.com/Windows/12.10/en/sound.html you will see the option I'm talking about, which was present on Opera 12.16 but not in Opera 12.17